# Running code returns with "color must int or tuple"

Tags: python, python-3.x, arcade

I was running a tower defence game in the arcade module but after I press start, the game freezes up and returns with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\arcade\text.py", line 278, in draw_text
    label = draw_text_cache[key]
KeyError: "05064200240left('Calibri', 'Arial')FalseFalse"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ThisPC\Downloads\The Great Skeleton War\lab_12.py", line 2890, in <module>
    arcade.run()
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\arcade\window_commands.py", line 236, in run
    pyglet.app.run()
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\__init__.py", line 107, in run
    event_loop.run()
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 167, in run
    timeout = self.idle()
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 243, in idle
    window.dispatch_event('on_draw')
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 1333, in dispatch_event
    if EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *args) != False:
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\pyglet\event.py", line 422, in dispatch_event
    self._raise_dispatch_exception(event_type, args, getattr(self, event_type), exception)
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\pyglet\event.py", line 476, in _raise_dispatch_exception
    raise exception
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\pyglet\event.py", line 415, in dispatch_event
    if getattr(self, event_type)(*args):
  File "C:\Users\ThisPC\Downloads\The Great Skeleton War\lab_12.py", line 1136, in on_draw
    arcade.render_text(globalvars.level_text, SCREEN_WIDTH - 104, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 50)
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\arcade\text.py", line 88, in render_text
    draw_text(text.text,
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\arcade\text.py", line 281, in draw_text
    image = get_text_image(text=text,
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\arcade\text.py", line 218, in get_text_image
    draw.multiline_text((image_start_x, image_start_y), text, text_color, align=align, font=font)
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 446, in multiline_text
    self.text(
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 365, in text
    ink = getink(fill)
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 313, in getink
    ink, fill = self._getink(fill)
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 112, in _getink
    ink = self.draw.draw_ink(ink)
TypeError: color must be int or tuple
```

And I'm not really sure why. It says my python packages are wrong so I uninstalled and reinstalled python multiple times too.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance btw.

Comment: I'm guessing there is something wrong with how you specify text color

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, this is hard. But here's my guess.

Perhaps it was made for Python 2 instead of Python 3, or the modules have been updated. Normally Python programs are run inside a virtual environments and have a requirements.txt file for the module versions. You can activate a virtual environment, install the packages and run it.

The issue arises from the wrong data type, the variable color should be of the type int or tuple.  On line 278 of the file "D:\lib\site-packages\arcade\text.py" in draw_text, what is the `type(key)`?

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it's hard to answer.

I think that when you decided the color that you wanted to use, probably in a text that you want to write on the screen, you chose the wrong format. You probably passed an array instead of a tuple that has this form: `(int, int, int)`. (for (r, g, b)) if you did use an array you can still use it but you'll have to add the `tuple(your_array)` command when you're passing it at the place you want to pass it to.